# Select All Checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-change

I have a select all checkbox and list check-box like this.
[image: Select All Checkbox]

A checkbox list receive data from

```
$scope.contacts = [
        {"name": "Bambizo", "check": false},
        {"name": "Jimmy", "check": false},
        {"name": "Tommy", "check": false},
        {"name": "Nicky", "check": false}
];
```

I want when i check a Select all checkbox, it make all checkbox in below list are checked or unchecked. And here my code:

**Select All Checkbox:**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAllContact" ng-change="checkAllContact(checkAllContact)">
```

**checkAllContact function:**

```
$scope.checkAllContact = function(){
        var allChecked = false;
        for(i = 0; i< $scope.contacts.length; i++){
            if ($scope.contacts[i].check == true){
                allChecked = true;
            }else {
                allChecked = false;
            }
        }

        if (allChecked = true){
            for(i = 0; i< $scope.contacts.length; i++){
                $scope.contacts[i].check = false;
            }
        }else{
            for(i = 0; i< $scope.contacts.length; i++){
                $scope.contacts[i].check = true;
            }    
        }
    }
```

But when i run and click Select All checkbox. It make an error:

[image: Error when after click checkbox]

How to solve it or have any other way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `ng-change="checkAllContact()"`?

Comment: It still make a error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-model="checkAllContact"` & method `checkAllContact` has same name.

`checkAllContact` scope variable is overriding by `checkAllContact`.

You need to change your function name will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks.It not make an error. But my function still not run :(. Can i run a function when check a checkbox?

Comment: @PhamMinhTan did you change your function name?

Comment: Yes, I did it. method and variables is different

Comment: @PhamMinhTan could you update your question with what you have tried till

Comment: @PhamMinhTan when you are going to do that.?

Comment: Sorry, my network was down. I will update later. Sorry.

Comment: @PhamMinhTan thats ok dude

Comment: Thanks @pankajparkar. I retry and my code is worked. Thanks for your support. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function name and variable name(ng-model) both are same, change one of them.

Also you can do it in a much simpler way, for an eg.

HTML:

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAllContact1" ng-change="checkAllContact()">
 <div ng-repeat="item in contacts">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.check"/>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.checkAllContact = function(){
    if ($scope.checkAllContact1) {
        $scope.checkAllContact1 = true;
    } else {
        $scope.checkAllContact1 = false;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.contacts, function (item) {
        item.check = $scope.checkAllContact1;
    });
}
```

See the example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/HB7LU/13555/)

Comment: I try to do like your answer. But my $scope.checkAllContact1 is always false.

Comment: @PhamMinhTan. Its working in my fiddle isn't it? If its still not working, can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Yes. your fiddle is running well. I will update my code in fiddle. Thanks.