# select all checkboxes in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am new AngularJS. I am trying select all checkboxes with single checkbox and also execute  `checkboxClick` method. because we setting values to scope. How to do that?

```
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" type="checkbox">Select All </input>
          <table class="table table-bordered">
                   <tr>
                       <th></th>
                       <th>Printed</th>
                       <th>First Name</th>
                       <th>Last Name</th>
                       <th>Company</th>
                       <th>City</th>
                       <th>Country</th>
                     </tr>
                     <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                        <td>
                           <input class="check-box" data-val="true" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-click="checkboxClick($event, item)">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                          {{item.printed}}
                          </td>
                          ....
                          ....
                      </tr>
                   </table>
```

JS

```
 $scope.checkboxClick = function (eventobj, item) {
        if (eventobj.target.checked) {
            $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
            $scope.getLabel(item.id);
            $scope.getOrderItems(item.id);
            $scope.getPaymentItems(item.id);
        } else {
            $scope.removeItemFromSelection(item);
        };
    };
```

Comment: Take look on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deeptechtons/TKVH6/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select All Checkbox in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120376/select-all-checkbox-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a function that is launched with the ng-click event on the checkbox. This will also unselect all checkbox too. It iterates through all items, changing the state of each.

```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
   <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>
            {{item.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
             <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The controller could look something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("checkboxCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.Items = [{
        name: "one"
    }, {
        name: "two"
    }, {
        name: "three"
    }];

    $scope.checkAll = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
            item.Selected = $scope.selectAll;
        });
    };   
});
```

Comment: select all and unselect all working fine. but `ng-click` function not firing for items when it is selected or unselected

Comment: @James123 are you sure you've added the controller in the correct place. If the input is outside the controller it will not work, as it doesn't have that function to use. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xcxf7p1y/).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a simple variable in your HTML :

```
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-click="checkboxClick($event, item)" ng-selected="checkAll">
<button ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes()">Check/Uncheck All</button>
```

and in your controller :

```
$scope.checkAll = false;
$scope.toggleAllCheckboxes = function(){
    $scope.checkAll = !$scope.checkAll;
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for button. `<input class="check-box" data-val="true" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"` is the checkboxes generated in table.